# $q$-deformations of fundamental equation of information and entropies

Tags: deformation-theory, it.information-theory, quantum-mechanics, entropy

- **Classical information theory: fundamental equation of information**

In classical information theory, the information $I(A)$ of an event $A$ (any element of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ of a given probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$, with probability measure $P$) is given by $I(A)=f(P(A))$, denoting by $f$ a real function defined on $[0,1]$. The axioms of information lead to the so called *fundamental equation of information* (FEI)

$$f(x)+(1-x)f\left(\frac{y}{1-x}\right)=f(y)+(1-y)f\left(\frac{x}{1-y}\right) $$

for $f$, on $D:=\{(x,y)~|~ x\in [0,1), y\in[0,1), x+y\leq 1\}$. Any function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ solution of FEI (plus some normalization) is called an information function. It is well known that the unique information function continuous on $[0,1]$ is given by the Shannon entropy

$$S(x):=x\ln \frac{1}{x}+(1-x)\ln\frac{1}{1-x},~~x\in (0,1),$$

with $S(0)=S(1):=0$. For more details I refer to the book ["On measures of information and their characterizations"](http://books.google.ch/books?id=9Xsj7AWmV8UC&pg=PR11&dq=Measures%20of%20information%20and%20their%20characterizations&hl=it&sa=X&ei=2esGVOHGMoip7Abb24DgBQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Measures%20of%20information%20and%20their%20characterizations&f=false) by Aczél & Daróczy.

- **$q$-deformations of Shannon entropy**

Let $q\in\mathbb R-\{1\}$ and $x>0$. The $q$-logarithm $\ln_q(\cdot)$ is the ratio $\ln_q x:= \frac{x^{1-q}-1}{q-1}$; it follows that $\lim_{q\rightarrow 1}\ln_q x = \ln x$ and, in particular,

$$\ln_q(xy)= \ln_q x + \ln_q y + (1-q)\ln_q x \ln_q y. $$

The $q$- logarithm is the inverse function of the $q$-exponential $e_q(\cdot)$, which is defined as the solution of the Cauchy problem  $\frac{dy}{dx}=y^q$, with $y(0)=1$.

The $q$-deformations of the logarithm are widely used in nonextensive statistical mechanics, quantum information theory and applications to introduce, in particular, the $q$- Tsallis entropy

$$S_q(x)=x \ln_q \frac{1}{x}+ (1-x)\ln_q \frac{1}{1-x} $$

and the $q$-Rényi entropy

$$R_q(x)= \ln e_q(S_q(x)). $$

Both $q$ entropies are deformations of Shannon entropy, as 
$$\lim_{q\rightarrow 1}S_q(x)=\lim_{q\rightarrow 1}R_q(x)=S(x),$$

although they are structurally different (w.r.t. extensivity property, for example).

For more details, I refer to the original paper 
 "[On measures of information and entropy](http://digitalassets.lib.berkeley.edu/math/ucb/text/math_s4_v1_article-27.pdf)" by Rényi and the book
["Introduction to Nonextensive Statistical Mechanics"](http://www.springer.com/physics/complexity/book/978-0-387-85358-1) by Tsallis.

- **Information theory for $q$-deformations of Shannon's entropy: main question**

I am searching for references on $q$-deformations of the FEI and classical information theory, to generate information solutions using $q$- Tsallis and $q$-Rényi entropies.
I am not aware of any paper on the subject; the main difficulties I met while trying to generalize "naively" the FEI are derived from the $q$-logarithm product rule. Introducing the $q$-product $\otimes_q$ and $q$-sum $\oplus_q$ (defined in Tsallis' book) did not help me much, so far. So my questions are

1. Is there any $q$-version of the classical information theory, with the definition of  $q$-information $I_q(\cdot)$?
2. Consequence of 1.: is there any reference on $q$-deformations FEI$_q$ of FEI, s.t. the $q$- Tsallis and/or $q$-Rényi entropies become information functions of it? I suppose that the FEI$_q$ descend from axioms satisfied by $I_q(\cdot)$ in 1.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. You know about Tsallis and Rényi entropies - so what is the exact question "1."? As you know, Rényi axiomatically defines entropy and arrives at a broader class than Shannon entropy. BTW: it is used, see e.g. [q-Gaussian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Gaussian_distribution).